# Java FX nullpointerexception to file path

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

I have been trying to follow the following tutorial https://o7planning.org/en/10623/javafx-tutorial-for-beginners and I am having a null pointer exception in line 15

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass()
                .getResource("src/application/MyScene.fxml"));
```

I tried changing the file paths to the following at no avail:

- MyScene.fxml
- application/MyScene.fxml
- src/application/MyScene.fxml

[image]

Comment: The argument to `getResource()` method call is wrong. Try removing "src/", i.e. `getClass().getResource("application/MyScene.fxml")`

Comment: tried it didnt work, same error

Comment: try `/MyScene.fxml` ?

Comment: nop, not working :'(

Comment: Should be `/application/MyScene.fxml` (Assuming your ide includes the file in the classpath at runtime)

Comment: Move `MyScene.fxml` to `resouce` and use  `/MyScene.fxml`